# How to Combine GeoQuery with another separate query in MongoDB and paginate result?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
let params = {
    $or: [

        {//STATUS1 PERSON
            status: { '$in': ['Status1'] }, object: { '$in': ['Person'] },
            geometry: {
                $near: {
                    $maxDistance: 160000,
                    $geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [geoCoordinates[1], geoCoordinates[0]]
                    }
                }
            },
            name: { '$in': req.user.names },
            sessionStartTime: { "$gte": new Date() },
            $and: [
                {
                    user_id: '',
                },
                {
                    userID: { $exists: false }
                }
            ]
        },
        { //STATUS1 ALL OTHER ITEM TYPES
            status: { '$in': ['Status1'] }, object: { '$in': ['Animal', 'Planet', 'Star'] },

            name: { '$in': req.user.names },
            sessionStartTime: { "$gte": new Date() },
            $and: [
                {
                    user_id: '',
                },
                {
                    userID: { $exists: false }
                }
            ]
        },
        { //ALL ITEM TYPES WITH STATUS2 AND STATUS3
            status: { '$in': ['Status2', 'Status3'] }, object: { '$in': ['Person', 'Animal', 'Planet', 'Star'] },
            user_id: req.user._id
        }

    ]
}

var options = {
    page: 1,
    limit: 5
};

let foundItems = await User.paginate(params, options).then(function (result) {

});
```

With this query, I'm getting the following error:

> MongoError: geoNear must be top-level expr

How do I include geometry query as one query among others and return the combined result with pagination ? Or is there a different way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Also, I'm using this to paginate: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2

Comment: You don't need to use an additional package to achieve pagination, you can use limit & sort of mongoDB to do that, Please check with aggregation in mongoDB, certainly many things can be easily achieved thru this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you CANNOT perform a geospatial query within the `$or` operation, it must be done at the very top level of your query. In other words, either the whole query must be geospatial or none of it.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the error. Is there another way to perhaps do two separate queries yet paginate the combined result?

Comment: @SunnyLy My apologies, I never received a notification for this. Yes, it's possible to paginate the results of multiple separate queries, although there are some limitations. If you take the results of all of your queries, collect the `_id`s of all of the documents matching those separate queries into an array, and then perform one final query for `{ _id: { $in: your_array_of_ids } }`, then you can absolutely accomplish this. Array/query size limitations may come into play, however, if you have many IDs in your array, so be aware of this.